# Browser won't fetch font files

Tags: html, css, svg, browser, fonts

I have a simple HTML demo page to try out my custom font files (a collection of SVG icons)

The HTML is rather simple, I specify the path for the font file (same directory as the HTML file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>nextgenicons</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }

        .preview {
            line-height: 2em;
        }

        .previewicon {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 32px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .icon {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        @font-face {
    font-family: "nextgenicons";
    src: url("nextgenicons.eot?95d1e9193d97fb68fae3bc44b221fa23?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("nextgenicons.woff2?95d1e9193d97fb68fae3bc44b221fa23") format("woff2"),
url("nextgenicons.woff?95d1e9193d97fb68fae3bc44b221fa23") format("woff"),
url("nextgenicons.svg?95d1e9193d97fb68fae3bc44b221fa23#nextgenicons") format("svg");
}

.icon {
    line-height: 1;
}

.icon:before {
    font-family: nextgenicons !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.icon-logo:before {
    content: "\f101";
}
.icon-ok:before {
    content: "\f102";
}
.icon-settings:before {
    content: "\f103";
}
.icon-menu:before {
    content: "\f104";
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>nextgenicons</h1>
    <div class="preview">
        <span class="previewicon">
            <span class=" icon-logo"></span>
        </span>
        <span>logo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <span class="previewicon">
            <span class=" icon-ok"></span>
        </span>
        <span>ok</span>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <span class="previewicon">
            <span class=" icon-settings"></span>
        </span>
        <span>settings</span>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <span class="previewicon">
            <span class=" icon-menu"></span>
        </span>
        <span>menu</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser just displays squares in place of the actual icons:

[image]

Here's the root directory, it has both the HTML page and the font files (please note the .html is the one with the IE icon, the other one with the Chrome icon is a .svg file):

[image]

What's more interesting is that the Browser doesn't fetch the font files, at all. Here's a snapshot of the network activity upon page load:

[image]

So I guess the black squares are shown because the Browser doesn't fetch the font file, but why is so?

Comment: the css file doesn't exist, it's embedded in the head section of the HTML file (as you can see on the question). Could it be that the problem?

Comment: @Pete no server is required, I just double click on the HTML page. I tried on a custom XAMPP instance and it does the same thing. The server can serve those file as it works for other more complex websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the icon class, but then you are not associate it in the dom `<span class=" icon-logo"></span>` should be `<span class="icon icon-logo"></span>`